# VBA/EXCEL Dynamic Named Range That Includes Both Text and Numbers

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

## Information

I have a column of about 300 part numbers that is constantly expanding. These part numbers can be only numbers, only letters, or a combination of both. I'm using dynamic named ranges with the part numbers to fill combobox lists. When the user types in the part number in the combobox, if we've done that part before it will autofill as they keep typing. I've recently ran into a problem with this however with a recent group of parts that was added.The part number is just a six digit number, and are the only part part numbers that solely consist of numbers, every other one has letters, or if its just numbers there are hyphens in the part number. The combobox I'm filling with this named range does show these numerical part numbers in its list, but does not autofill them when the user types and does not autofill the other information associated with the part number in other textboxes when the part number is done being typed in.

### Question

Can anyone help me understand why it isn't autofilling the numerical value but it fills every other value?

### Code

Here is the code I'm using to fill the combobox list and the dynamic range formula. Let me know if you need anything else to help you give an answer.

```
=OFFSET('Part List'!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA('Part List'!$A:$A),1)    

comboxPartNumber.List = Range("Part_Number").Value

List of Sample Parts
X-600-ASSY-SM
LO-5093-020-023
LO-5093-020-025
AB-1541754
764761
766415
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample data of Part list?

Comment: Yes, I edited the original post with a sample list, there is no consistent format for the numbers because every vendor has a different system.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add a comment, sice I am 2 points short :(, so I am forced to post this as a solution:

Try to make all the numbers strings.

```
Dim R As Range
For Each R In Range("Part_Number").Cells
    If IsNumeric(R.FormulaLocal) Then R.FormulaLocal = "'" & R.FormulaLocal
Next
```

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Instead I used `CStr(comboboxPartNum.value) = Cstr(Sheet3.Range("A" & i ).offset(1).value)` which is where it compares the user entered part number in the combobox to my Range of part numbers in another sheet. Now it fills in the information associated with the part number but only when the part number is completely filled in. It still will not autocomplete the part number as I'm typing in the combobox.